# Implied volatility and pricing of vanilla options

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility

As far as I understood, implied volatility (IV) is a lucky parametrization of the vanilla option's price. That is, instead of deciding how much the call worth now, you can decide on its IV and put this in the Black-Scholes (BS) formula since all other inputs (underlying price, time to maturity etc.) are readily available. In that case, we use IV $\sigma$ as a free variable which we adjust to fit the market prices.

This parametrization and the choice of the free variable is by no means unique: for example, we can say that instead of BS price for call $V(S,\sigma,\dots)$ we invent $W(S,\sigma,\alpha,\dots) = \alpha\cdot V(S,\sigma,\dots)$. In that case, we may estimate $\sigma$ as a 30-days end-of-day volatility of underlying returns (so that it becomes a measurable from market data, fixed quantity) and let $\alpha$ be a new free variable. It will have a similar effect: raise $\alpha$ to raise call price, and we can talk in term of implied $\alpha$ surface rather that IV surface.

The popularity of the IV parametrization seems to be in the fact that it's simpler, we just use the BS framework and don't have to come up with new variables. Am I right, or am I missing some points here?

The IV is hence an inconsistent model: it's like we pick up a random formula (say BS formula) with one free variable, and just try to fit the output to the market prices by changing the value of this variable. Because of that, we can't do much against the market - in contrast, would the CRR binomial model predict statistics of underlying prices correctly, if we get a market price significantly different from the CRR price, we can trade it and make a risk-free profit by hedging. The IV approach does not even seem to have a potential here: you are relying on the market prices, and cannot say whether they are right or wrong. Am I right here as well?

For the reasons above, I have the following question. Gatheral writes that more consistent stochastic volatility models are used to derive values for exotic options, parameters being fitted over the vanilla options prices. Does it mean that we can't do better with vanilla option prices just by using the IV approach?

Please tell me if the question is not clear, I'd be happy to fix that.

Comment: As Mark Joshi pointed out your questions seem philosophical. Vanilla option prices are nothing more than a reflection of the market's take on implied volatility. How you arrive at such volatility estimate is entirely up to you. If you believe you have a superior model to arrive at implied volatilities (aka, if you think you are able to better predict future price variation of the underlying) then employ whatever you like and trade it against market prices. You should over time extract alpha if your model is indeed superior.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Isn't coming up with an opinion on BS IV is equivalent to having an opinion on absolute prices of the vanilla options, since all other inputs for the BS model are available? If my understanding is right, then your comment reads to me pretty much as: to determine prices of vanilla options (in dollar units) we need to determine prices of vanilla options (in volatility units), but I am not sure whether it's what you meant.

Comment: Partially, instead of occupying your time to predict future option prices you can "simplify" by predicting the implied volatility. Not that it is any easier but you somewhat boil it down to the essential. Some option traders believe they are more successful at modeling volatility than modeling asset prices. Hence they hedge out other risk exposures and focus on volatility trading. Btw, other BS inputs are anything but static over time. Consider the underlying price, consider even something as "trivial" as dividend curves of single name equity options.

Comment: @MattWolf: thanks, that's was my idea. So essentially, volatility in this sense is a useful parametrization of price that allows focusing mostly on pricing this parameters. According to this reasoning, trading vanilla options is direct - you can't really always say whether the market prices options wrong or right, unlike in the BS world (I hope I clarified this in my comment to Mark Joshi).

Comment: Forget the "BS world". BS is a translation tool, it means next to nothing. It is a market agreed tool to statically express volatility in terms of currency denominated price. Hence it is completely irrelevant whether BS exhibits flaws or not as long as all market practitioners agree on the usage of the exact same tool (which they do, at least in the equity world). BS simply translates your volatility figure into a tradable price at inception of the trade. Nothing else. What the market is trading is volatility not option prices.

Comment: @MattWolf I understand the translation function of BS framework. By the "BS world" I mean the following situation. Imagine, we play a game and we simulate prices using GBM with constant drift and vol, everything is common knowledge. I tell you that I'd like to buy a call. If the price you show me is much lower than the BS value, and I can hedge with no transaction costs, BS framework tells me how to make a risk-free profit (modulo gamma variance). So, for me BS has a double role: 1) in reality we can use it to translate prices to vols 2) if the stock prices would follow BS [ctd]

Comment: [ctd] or in the game I've described, BS would also tell me what to do if market prices disagree with theoretical prices. I wonder, whether there are models with the latter feature that are used in reality to price vanilla options. I would expect this from stochastic volatility models, but apparently they are not used for vanilla, only for exotic, whereas vanilla options are priced by traders directly based on their point of view (on price in vol terms), rather than on theory. The discussion is long, but some things became clearer to me, so thanks for elaborating.

Comment: I believe that implied volatility of any basic asset has to be formulated. Whether you agree with market consensus or whether you build your own forecasting model. The same applies to exotic products with complexity of your choice. The volatility models perused there depend on the very same basic building blocks such as a vanilla option and its implied volatility. So, even stochastic volatility models rely on the same basic mechanics than your own implied volatility forecasting model. Volatility is not deterministic and hence anyone who can model future volatility better than the market will

Comment: ...be able to extract risk adjusted value. I do not have more to add to this except maybe mentioning that BS does not itself prescribe how you are to hedge an option position but its derivatives do prescribe how to hedge specific risks.

Comment: @MattWolf: thanks, maybe you want to formulate part of your comments as an answer so that other could easier go through that? I'd certainly upvote it for the least.

Comment: You can parameterize option prices using whatever model you like, V/42 for instance. That model is unlikely to be as illuminating as Black-Scholes though.

Comment: @experquisite: that's exactly my point, and I don't question the usefulness of the BS parametrization. Rather, I wonder whether it has some value for pricing vanilla options beyond being a useful parametrization. Also, what's v/42 model? Or do you mean the vol divided by the ultimate answer?

Comment: A large contingent will view the question as meaningless, since vanilla option prices are quoted, hence don't need to be priced.  The model clearly is not correct, since there exist volatility smiles.  It is arguably useful to price those vanilla options which are not exactly quoted, by interpolating the implied volatility.  I suppose it depends if you are trying to price vanillas better than the market, or more interested in pricing non-vanillas which you can hedge with vanillas, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

CRR is just a numerical approximation to Black--Scholes. Its main use is in getting American option price. There is no real difference other than slight inaccuracy when using it for Europeans. So no it wouldn't do what you ask.

Your questions are philosophical. What is the purpose of the model? if you estimate the volatility from a time series then you can use it to assess the prices of vanilla options. If you fit it to vanilla options then you can't but you can then use it to price exotics.

You might find looking Rebonato's Volatility and Correlation helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry, I should have indicated that I used CRR instead of BS since even if the stock prices would follow BS, we still won't be able to hedge them continuously, whereas in CRR case we can do perfect hedging. That's a minor point, though. I do agree with your second paragraph. To clarify, I wonder if there exists a model to price *vanilla* options with the following BS feature: if market price is far from the model price, the model would also tell me how to make an (almost) risk-free profit from that situation.

Comment: well BS gives you a hedging strategy that will realize the replication price if you have the correct volatility. You have to hedge continuously which is impossible but if you hedge frequently you only get a very small error so you can realize the arbitrage.

Comment: Leaving variance caused by imperfect hedging errors, could you clarify what do you mean by having *the correct volatility*? AFAIK, if the underlying price follows GMB with deterministic time-dependent diffusion coefficient $\sigma(t)$ (in particular, if $\sigma$ is constant) then the knowledge of $\sigma$ indeed tells us how to realize the replication price. However, I am not sure whether this even theoretically applies already to the case of stochastic $\sigma$ since the market is incomplete.